# Swagger jaxrs. How to generate single enum reference for all data objects

Tags: kotlin, swagger, jax-rs, swagger-codegen

I use kotlin + Jersey and swagger documentation generator with the approach `code first`.

I have two DTO

```
enum class DataType {
  FIRST, SECOND;
}

data class Data1(type: DataType)

data class Data2(type: DataType)
```

gradle dependency

```
implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta:2.2.6")
```

Expected result for documentation:

```
components:
  schemas:
    DataType:
      type: string
      enum: [ FIRST, SECOND ]
    Data1:
      type: object
      properties:
        type: 
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataType'
    Data2:
      type: object
      properties:
        type: 
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataType'
```

Actual result

```
components:
  schemas:
    Data1:
      type: object
      properties:
        type: 
          type: string
          enum: [ FIRST, SECOND ]
    Data2:
      type: object
      properties:
        type: 
          type: string
          enum: [ FIRST, SECOND ]
```

The problem is, that if any client reuses schema to generate classes for his own app, he gets two separate enum classes for the type property.

**Q: How to make generator to detect that it is the same enum and extract it to separate type reference?**

Comment: If you annotate the enum class with `@Schema(enumAsRef=true)` as [shown here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3124#issuecomment-773179552) (or whatever the equivalent Kotlin syntax is), does this produce the expected result?

Comment: I use enum from domain layer and do not want that class to know anything about swagger annotations

Comment: Can you try setting `io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.enumsAsRef` to `true` as [suggested here](https://springdoc.org/#how-can-i-apply-enumasref-true-to-all-enums)?

Comment: There is no such property in the configuration, but the system property could be set up

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found one approach myself

```
import io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.SET_PROPERTY_OF_ENUMS_AS_REF

init {
  System.setProperty(SET_PROPERTY_OF_ENUMS_AS_REF, "any value")
}
```

The other way is to implement a custom `ModelResolver`, but the class implementation looks quite complicated

**UDPATE**
Just noticed, that `public static boolean enumsAsRef = System.getProperty("enums-as-ref") != null;` in `ModelResolver` is not final. So we can do even simpler

```
init {
  io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.enumsAsRef = true
}
```